# Can not pass value from Ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

My AJAX:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to('dashboard') }}',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { cid: val },
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#status-msg').addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $('#status-msg').text('Fejl!!');
        }
    });
```

My Route:

My Controller:

```
    public function dashboard(){
        if (Request::ajax()){
            $cid = Input::get('cid');
            var_dump(json_encode($cid));
        } else {
            echo "XX";
        }      
    }
```

The cid is not passing to controller, the request AJAX is not working.

Comment: If you look in the network console of your browser do you see something like this: `/dashboard?cid=val` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try change your ajax type to POST ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to("yourURL") }}',
        type:'POST',
        data:"cid="+$(this).val()+"&_token=" + $("input[name=_token]").val(),
        dataType:'JSON',            
        success:function(result){
        },
        error: function() {

        }

  });
```

Edit:

try to pass _token if you use {{Form::open}}.

hope this will help.

Comment: have you try to change how to pass data like `data:"cid="+$(this).val()&_token=" + $("input[name=_token]").val(),`. You can fetch the data in controller use `Input::all()` to fetch all the value like `$input = Input::all();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/contorller_name/method_name',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { cid: val },
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: function(result) {},
   error: function() {
      $('#status-msg').addClass('alert alert-danger');
      $('#status-msg').text('Fejl!!');
   }
});
```

Comment: I have not tried this, but could be but how is it different the other way?

Comment: Do you have latest jquery library inserted. Because you are using jquery.